# How to Update the parent component when child component updates in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, components, local-storage

I have a child component that's basically four checkbox that has values from 1 to 4,
so here's my problem, each time the user clicks on one of them it should pass the value to my `api` and it will return item's based on that value, the problem i'm facing is those i don't know how to pass those values to parent and i want the parent component to update each time the user clicks on one of the checkbox, the `componentDidUpdate` method works fine in the child component, but it doesn't have any effect on parent component, and here's what i do in child component:

```
class PriceRange extends React.Component {
    state = {
        checked5: false,
        checked6: false,
        checked7: false,
        checked8: false,
        checked9: false,
        FilterPrice: ''
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        localStorage.setItem("FilterPrice", this.state.FilterPrice)
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("FilterPrice"))
    }

    render() {
        const clearFilters = () => {
            this.setState({
                checked5: false,
                checked6: false,
                checked7: false,
                checked8: false,
                checked9: false,
                FilterPrice : null
            });
        }
        return (
            <div className="day-range price-range col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
                <div className="title">
                    <div className="range">
                        <span>محدوده قیمت</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="clear" onClick={clearFilters}>
                        <div className="icon">
                            <i className="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <span> حذف فیلترها</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Checkbox
                        nativeControlId='5'
                        checked={this.state.checked5}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({
                                checked5: e.target.checked,
                                checked6: false,
                                checked7: false,
                                checked8: false,
                                checked9: false,
                                FilterPrice: 5
                            })

                        }

                        }
                        onClick={this.props.action}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor='5'>کمتر از 100,000 تومان</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Checkbox
                        nativeControlId='6'
                        checked={this.state.checked6}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({
                                checked6: e.target.checked,
                                checked5: false,
                                checked7: false,
                                checked8: false,
                                checked9: false,
                                FilterPrice: 6
                            })

                        }

                        }
                        onClick={this.props.action}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor='6'>از 100,000 تومان تا 200,000 تومان</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Checkbox
                        nativeControlId='7'
                        checked={this.state.checked7}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({
                                checked7: e.target.checked,
                                checked6: false,
                                checked5: false,
                                checked8: false,
                                checked9: false,
                                FilterPrice: 7
                            })

                        }

                        }
                        onClick={this.props.action}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor='7'>از 200,000 تومان تا 400,000 تومان</label>

                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Checkbox
                        nativeControlId='8'
                        checked={this.state.checked8}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({
                                checked8: e.target.checked,
                                checked6: false,
                                checked7: false,
                                checked5: false,
                                checked9: false,
                                FilterPrice: 8
                            })
                        }

                        }
                        onClick={this.props.action}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor='8'>از 400,000 تومان تا 600,000 تومان</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <Checkbox
                        nativeControlId='9'
                        checked={this.state.checked9}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            this.setState({
                                checked9: e.target.checked,
                                checked6: false,
                                checked7: false,
                                checked8: false,
                                checked5: false,
                                FilterPrice: 9
                            })

                        }

                        }
                        onClick={this.props.action}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor='9'>بیشتر از 600,000 تومان</label>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }



}

export default PriceRange;
```

and what i'm using for the parent component is something like this,

```
state = {
   priceRange:localStorage.getItem("FilterPrice")
}



componentDidUpdate(){
     if(this.state.priceRange==localStorage.getItem("FilterPrice")){
        console.log("same")

     }else{
         this.setState({priceRange:localStorage.getItem("FilterPrice")})
         console.log(this.state.priceRange)
     }  
}
```

so basically i have two questions here, how can i pass those values without using `localstorage` and how can i update the parent component whenever the user clicks on one of checkboxes?

Comment: lift the state up. let the parent manage the state and pass the values on change handlers to the child components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In parent define a function. e.g:

```
const getCheckboxValue =(checkboxVlueFromChild)=>{
    //call your api or do some stuff in parent.
}
```

Pass this function to your child component. e.g:

```
<Checkbox ... getCheckboxValue={getCheckboxValue} />
```

In child, on change of checkbox call getCheckboxValue function and pass the value as argument. e,g

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
   props.getCheckboxValue(e.target.value);
}
```